# Sorbet Ruby: Set type signature as "datetime" for ISO8601

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorbet

New to both ruby and sorbet – but excited.

I can't tell if it's just not supported or if I'm reading the documentation incorrectly but I can't seem to find a type for Datetimes on Sorbet.org.

I'm looking to check that `"2019-07-15T16:15:13-04:00"` is not only a string but an ISO8601 datetime.

Something to this effect:

```rb
  sig {params(location_id: String, starts_at: Datetime, ends_at: Datetime).returns(HTTParty::Response)}
  def get_availability(location_id, starts_at, ends_at)
    self.class.get("/availabilities/?location_id=#{location_id}&starts_at=#{starts_at}&ends_at=#{ends_at}", {
      headers: make_headers
    })
  end
```

Comment: The ruby class is `DateTime` with an upper case `T` not sure if this is supported but it will avoid what I can only assume is `UnInitialized Constant` errors right now

Comment: Also `DateTime` is not an ISO8601 datetime. Its a class that encapsulates pretty much the whole concept of time. ISO8601 is just a set of standards for string representation of a timestamp. `DateTime` just happens to use ISO8601 when you call `.to_s` on it. You should also consider the use of `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone`.

Comment: Not an answer to your question but if you're truly new to Ruby then don't start out using Sorbet. Learn Ruby first, then look into the utility (or not) of Sorbet.